# Jquery variables not comparing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to grab the results from this 3 elements, it updates every time I click a button

```
<span id="machine1Result" class="slotMachine noBorder">0</span>
<span id="machine2Result" class="slotMachine noBorder">0</span>
<span id="machine3Result" class="slotMachine noBorder">0</span>
```

with this code trying to grab the 3 combined values of the element, if matched I was able to do some changing:

```
var text = $('#machine1Result,#machine2Result,#machine3Result').text();
var comparingText0 = "000";
var comparingText1 = "111";

if (text == comparingText0) {
    $('.wonbg').css({'background-image': 'url(img/won_bg.png)'});
    $('.rw14').css({'backgroundColor': '#ff9900'});
    count += 1;
}
if (text == comparingText1) {
    $('.wonbg').css({'background-image': 'url(img/won_bg.png)'});
    $('.rw1').css({'backgroundColor': '#ff9900'});
    count += 1;
}
else {
    $('.slotMachineButton').click(function() {

        $('.wonbg').css({"background": "none"});
        $('.rewards').css({"background": "none"});

    });
}
```

the code above runs the condition properly if the elements has the same number, but it also functions even if there's one wrong number say 110 or 101 and vise versa, tried `===` giving me same results.

Comment: that selector won't combine the text. you will have to do that manually.

Comment: i was trying get the result of the three element so when they are matched i can fire up a condition.

Comment: [Wow that really does work.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/febyE) It's a little weird that it's not symmetric with `.html()`. Learn something every day.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to answer this question. Different values work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hz143qzo/

Comment: Do a `console.log()` of your two values to see exactly why they don't match.  Put a delimiter on each end of the string you log so you can see if there's a whitespace mismatch at the end.  `console.log('"' + text + '"');`.

Answer (score 1):

If the first condition is true, it will also fire the else. That is because this line

```
if ( text == comparingText1 ) {
```

should be an else if

```
else if ( text == comparingText1 ) {
```

and now all the conditions will be linked.

Bow the other issue is text is text()

```
var text = $('#machine1Result,#machine2Result,#machine3Result').text();
```

EDIT: since what you gave is wrong, I have to change the answer....

text)_ will only give the first answer, so you would need to loop through them

```
var results = $('#machine1Result,#machine2Result,#machine3Result');
results.each( function() { 
    var currentLine = $(this);
    var currentText = currentLine.text();
    console.log(currentText);
} );
```

Comment: same results the condition still fires up, i included the code `console.log('"' + text + '"');` @jfriend00 it gave me 3 result in a row `""000"" ""000"" and ""001""`

Comment: Wait so what you showed above in the sample html and in this comment does not match...

Comment: btw im using a plugin from here [http://josex2r.github.io/jQuery-SlotMachine/] from the page you can see index result on whats currently active below the machine.

Comment: yup it does not match but still it applied the condition.

Comment: well no, it is like saying I give you a a dollar bill for a ten dollar item because the one matches the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, the plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/slotmachine/ itself is causing late detection of the elements final result:

after the plugin stops and set the results there's a 1.3 sec delay before it writes the final result like let say `000` then it writes another `001, 011` finally the result `111` i notice it when injecting the `alert();` it alerted me for more than 3 with different results, it also happening at `console.log()` by sending more than 4 to 5 request.

all i did is to set a timeout of 1.3 sec when the final result happens, so:

```
setTimeout(function () {
var results = $('#machine1Result, #machine2Result, #machine3Result').text();
var comparingText0 = "000";
var comparingText1 = "111";

        if ( results == comparingText0 ) { 
            $('.wonbg').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/won_bg.png)'});
            $('.rw14').css({'backgroundColor' : '#ff9900'});
            count += 1;
        }
        else if ( results == comparingText1 ) { 
            $('.wonbg').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/won_bg.png)'});
            $('.rw1').css({'backgroundColor' : '#ff9900'});
            count += 1;
        }
        else {
            $( '.slotMachineButton' ).click(function() {

                $('.wonbg').css({"background" : "none"});
                $('.rewards').css({"background" : "none"});

            });
        }
    }, 1300);
```